# Is there any valid reason for declaring a Quartz Job as a spring bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

By looking at some examples of running quartz jobs in a spring boot app, I see many of them are actually declaring the `Job` with the `@Component` annotation :

- [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule#1-job) example
- [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-quartz-to-spring-boot) example
- [Medium](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9) example

It seems to be completly useless as the job factory will create a new instance every time the job is triggered.

I can see in my app that the method [SpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SpringBeanJobFactory.java#L88) is called each time the job is executed. I removed the `@Component` annotation and it works perfectly, so is there any advantage of declaring a Job as a spring bean ?

Comment: Hi Olivier, I have a doubt too. I see that you've asked this question 5 months ago, do you know maybe the answer? Do you use @Component on your `Job`s?

Comment: I don't use `@Component` unless I want to inject the `Job` in another class of my app. If you don't have this requirement, you can declare your job without using `@Component`. You can add a breakpoint into the job's constructor, you will see a new one is created by spring at each execution.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you need to inject spring managed components into your job, for example some service or repository (to get some data to process by job). In such case, you wanna create a job as a component and allows spring to inject required beans into it. In such case your job's superclass can extend QuartzJobBean.